# Proof that a function is nonzero given constraints on $x$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $f(x)=a_{n} x^{n}+a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{1} x+a_{0}, \;\left(a_{n} \neq 0\right) .$

Let $A=\max \left\{\left|a_{0}\right|,\left|a_{1}\right|, \ldots,\left|a_{n}\right|\right\}$.

Let $f(x)=a_{n} x^{n}+a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{1} x+a_{0}, \left(a_{n} \neq 0\right) .$ 
and let $B=n A /\left|a_{n}\right|,$ Show that $f(x) \neq 0$ if $|x|>B .$

I have been trying to do this by induction and have successfully proved the base case but am unable to prove the induction step. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Induction won't be useful here since the set you're working with is uncountable. Unfortunately, my brain keeps telling me to use Rouche's theorem which is way outside the scope of your course.

Comment: @CameronWilliams yes this is from the first chapter of an introductory real analysis course textbook

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is obvious that $B=nA/{a_n}\ge n\ge1$

For $|x|>B$, we have $\frac{|f(x)|}{a_n|x|^n}\ge|1|-|\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}x^{-1}|-...-|\frac{a_0}{a_n}x^{-n}|\gt 1-\frac B n (B^{-1}+B^{-2}+...+B^{-n})\ge1-\frac Bn(nB^{-1})=0$

Comment: The idea is that the first item $a_nx^n$ grows fastly so that as |x| goes larger enough,  the absolute value of $a_nx^n$ will be larger than the sum of all other items.